# ¿Cómo comparar si una cadena es subcadena en todos los items de una lista en python?

Tags: python

Tengo una lista y una cadena. Lo que quiero es mirar si la cadena es una subsecuencia en cada uno de los items de la lista, al final tengo que devolver dos listas, primera en donde estén los items que tienen la cadena, y la segunda con los que no.

Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código, pero solo devuelve los items haciendo la evaluación en la ultima letra de la cadena. Quiero que me devuelva los items haciendo la evaluación en todos los items, por lo que si todos las letras de la cadena están en los items de la lista, ese item se devuelva en la primera lista y si no entonces ese item se devuelva en la segunda lista.

Por ejemplo, si tengo:
Lista = ["salud", "kiwi", "silla", "lila"]
cadena = "sal"

Quiero que devuelva:
PrimeraLista = ["salud", "silla"]
SegundaLista = ["kiwi", "lila"]

```
lista = ["salud", "kiwi", "silla", "lila"]
cadena = "sal"
PrimeraLista=[]
SegundaLista=[]

Booleano= True

for x in lista:
  print(x)
  for y in cadena:
    print (y)
    if y not in x:
      Booleano= False
    if y in x:  
    Booleano= True
  if Booleano == False: 
    SegundaLista.append(x)
  if Booleano == True: 
    PrimeraLista.append(x)
print (SegundaLista) 
print ( PrimeraLista)
```

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenido Cris c:

Aquí te ofresco un par de formas de lograr lo que buscas:

#### Con comprensión de listas

Aquí te dejo un link donde se explican las comprensiones de lista: https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/funcionalidades-avanzadas/comprension-de-listas/

```
palabras = ["salud", "kiwi", "silla", "lila"]
letras = "sal"
coincidencias = []
no_coincidencias = []

for palabra in palabras:
    if(all((l in palabra) for l in letras)):
        # Si todas las letras de la variable letras están en la palabra, entonces agrego la palabra a la lista coincidencias.
        coincidencias.append(palabra)
    else:
        # Si falta al menos una letra, la pongo en la lista no_coincidencias
        no_coincidencias.append(palabra)

print()
print("coincidencias", coincidencias)
print("No coinciden", no_coincidencias)
```

#### Sin comprensión de listas

```
palabras = ["salud", "kiwi", "silla", "lila"]
letras = "sal"
coincidencias = []
no_coincidencias = []

for palabra in palabras:
    # Asumo que estarán todas las letras
    tiene_todas_las_letras = True

    for l in letras:
        if(l not in palabra):
            # Si alguna letra de letras falta en palabra, le digo al programa que no tiene todas las letras y dejo de recorrer las letras.
            tiene_todas_las_letras = False
            break

    if(tiene_todas_las_letras):
        coincidencias.append(palabra)
    else:
        no_coincidencias.append(palabra)


print()
print("coincidencias", coincidencias)
print("No coinciden", no_coincidencias)
```

Comment: creo que seri un *Plus* si explicas la compresión de lista

Comment: Voy a dejar un link hacia una pagina que lo explica

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una respuesta complementaria a la de @Dante-S, de hecho es casi igual, solo que usando [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) y una [función anónima](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

```
PrimeraLista = list(filter(lambda x:all(el in x for el in cadena), lista))
SegundaLista = list(x for x in lista if x not in PrimeraLista)
```

Probablemente la respuesta de Dante sea más eficiente porque `SegundaLista` está siendo calculada en el mismo `for` que `PrimeraLista`, pero para propósitos académicos y conceptuales vale. No quiere decir que mientras menos código se escribe es mejor, pero en Python hay que acostumbrarse a ver esto.

Por si alguien pregunta, no se usó `SegundaLista = list(set(lista) - set(PrimeraLista))`, porque creo esto desordena la lista resultante (y elimina registros duplicados). Si lo anterior no es problema, entonces también sirve.